# Desing pattern for background working app

Tags: objective-c, ios5, background-process, cocoa-design-patterns

I have created a web-service app and i want to populate my view controllers according to the response i fetch(via GET) in main thread. But i want to create a scheduled timer which will go and control my server, if there becomes any difference(let's say if the count of an array has changed) i will create a local notification. As far as i read from here and some google results, i cant run my app in background more then ten minutes expect from some special situations(Audio, Vo-IP, GPS).. But i need to control the server at least one per minute.. Can anyone offer some idea-or link please?

**EDIT**
I will not sell the app in store, just for a local area network. Let's say, from the server i will send some text messages to the users and if a new message comes, the count of messages array will increment, in this situation i will create a notification. I need to keep this 'controlling' routing alive forever, whether in foreground or background. Does GCD give such a solution do anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply play a mute audio file in loop in the background, OR, ping the user's location in the background. Yes, that will drain the battery a bit, but it's a simple hack for in-home applications. Just remember to enable the background types in your `Info.plist`!

Comment: If you have some sample code-or tutorial can you share please? If not i will try anyway:)

Comment: thanks, i'm not so experienced with programming so i asked for tutorials:) but i think i will grab it easy

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** "[...] I fetch (via GET) in main thread."  This is not a good approach.  You should *never* fetch any network resources on the main thread. Why?  Because your GUI, which is maintained by the main thread, will become unresponsive whenever a fetch isn't instantaneous.  Any lag spike on the network results in a less than desirable user experience.

**Answer:** Aside from the listed special situations, you can't run background apps.  The way I see it:

- Don't put the app in the background.  (crappy solution)
- Try putting another "entity" between the app and the "server".  I don't know why you "need to control the server at least one per minute" but perhaps you can delegate this "control" to another process outside the device?

.

```
iOS app  ->  some form of proxy server -> server which requires
                                          "babysitting" every minute.
```

Comment: I will not sell the app in store, just for a local area network. Let's say, from the server i will send some text messages to the users and if a new message comes, the count of messages array will increment, in this situation i will create a notification. I need to keep this 'controlling' routing alive forever, whether in foreground or background. Does GCD give such a solution do you have any idea?